# Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InvalidMetadataException

Tags: fxcop

```
<FxCopReport Version="10.0">
<Exceptions>
<Exception Keyword="CA0001" Kind="Engine">
<Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InvalidMetadataException    </Type>
<ExceptionMessage>
The following error was encountered while reading module 'myproject': Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid.
</ExceptionMessage>
<StackTrace>
at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.HandleError(ModuleNode mod, String errorMessage) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeSignature(MemoryCursor sigReader, Boolean& pinned, Boolean& isTypeArgument) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeList(MemoryCursor sigReader) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeSignature(MemoryCursor sigReader, Boolean& pinned, Boolean& isTypeArgument) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeList(MemoryCursor sigReader) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeSignature(MemoryCursor sigReader, Boolean& pinned, Boolean& isTypeArgument) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseParameterTypes(TypeNodeCollection& varArgTypes, MemoryCursor sigReader, Int32 paramCount, Boolean& genericParameterEncountered) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMemberFromRef(Int32 i, TypeNodeCollection& varArgTypes, Int32 numGenericArgs) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodDefOrRef(Int32 codedIndex, Int32 numberOfGenericArguments) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodFromSpec(Int32 i) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMemberFromToken(Int32 tok, TypeNodeCollection& varArgTypes) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstruction() at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstructions() at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseMethodInstructions(Method method, Int32 methodIndex, Int32 RVA) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodInstructions(Method method, Object i) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodBody(Method method, Object i, Boolean asInstructionList) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Method.get_Instructions() at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.RuleUtilities.HasImperativeSecurityAction(Method method, SecurityAction action) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.RuleUtilities.HasSecurityAction(Method method, SecurityAction action) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.RuleUtilities.HasSecurityAction(Method method, SecurityAction[] actions) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.RecordCallSites(Method caller) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitMember(Member member, TargetMember target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitMembers(MemberCollection members, TargetMemberDictionary targets, Boolean visitNestedTypes) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitTypes(TypeNodeCollection types, TargetNamespaceDictionary targets) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitModule(ModuleNode module, TargetModule target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitAssembly(AssemblyNode assembly, TargetFile target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.VisitAssembly(AssemblyNode assembly, TargetFile target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.Load(TargetFile target, Boolean buildTree, Boolean queueItems, AssemblyNode loadedAssembly) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.LoadVisitor.LoadAssemblies(Queue queue, ExceptionCollection exceptions)
</StackTrace>
</Exception>
<Exception Keyword="CA0001" Kind="Engine">
<Type>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.FxCopException    </Type>
<ExceptionMessage>
An unhandled exception occurred while analyzing assemblies:
</ExceptionMessage>
<InnerType>Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InvalidMetadataException    </InnerType>
<InnerExceptionMessage>
The following error was encountered while reading module 'myproject': Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid.
</InnerExceptionMessage>
<InnerStackTrace>
at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.HandleError(ModuleNode mod, String errorMessage) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeSignature(MemoryCursor sigReader, Boolean& pinned, Boolean& isTypeArgument) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeList(MemoryCursor sigReader) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeSignature(MemoryCursor sigReader, Boolean& pinned, Boolean& isTypeArgument) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeList(MemoryCursor sigReader) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseTypeSignature(MemoryCursor sigReader, Boolean& pinned, Boolean& isTypeArgument) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseParameterTypes(TypeNodeCollection& varArgTypes, MemoryCursor sigReader, Int32 paramCount, Boolean& genericParameterEncountered) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMemberFromRef(Int32 i, TypeNodeCollection& varArgTypes, Int32 numGenericArgs) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodDefOrRef(Int32 codedIndex, Int32 numberOfGenericArguments) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodFromSpec(Int32 i) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMemberFromToken(Int32 tok, TypeNodeCollection& varArgTypes) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstruction() at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.InstructionParser.ParseInstructions() at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.ParseMethodInstructions(Method method, Int32 methodIndex, Int32 RVA) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodInstructions(Method method, Object i) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Reader.GetMethodBody(Method method, Object i, Boolean asInstructionList) at Microsoft.FxCop.Sdk.Method.get_Instructions() at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.UpdateSourceContext(SourceContext& sourceContext, Method method) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.LogProblems(Method method, TargetMember target, Rule rule, ProblemCollection problems) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.LogProblems(Member member, TargetMember target, Rule rule, ProblemCollection problems) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.CheckMember(Member memberToAnalyze, Member member, TargetMember target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.VisitMember(Member member, TargetMember target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.BaseVisitor.VisitMembers(MemberCollection members, TargetMemberDictionary targets, Boolean visitNestedTypes) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.VisitType(TypeNode type, TargetType target) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.AnalysisVisitor.Analyze(Queue queue) at Microsoft.FxCop.Engines.Introspection.IntrospectionAnalysisEngine.AnalyzeThread()
</InnerStackTrace>
</Exception>
</Exceptions>
</FxCopReport>
```

I got the following errors when running fxcop code analysis, anyone seen these before, i am not sure why it's telling "Method type parameter in position 0 is not valid"?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Code Contracts or PostSharp or some other post-compilation step that fiddles with the IL?

I've just started getting this - in my case, it went away when I changed the Code Contract's Runtime Checks from "Full" to "Pre and Post", so it looks like something dodgy in ccrewrite.exe.